# Zabbix: Is it possible to show the uptime of all hosts in a single graph?

Tags: zabbix

I found no up to date information on this.
Background is that I want to see for all workstations (all or maybe also a group) when they are online and when they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want a graph (which will be unreadable) but some other visualisation.

For your needs [network maps](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/visualisation/maps/map) might be better. That will give you an area with each host represented by an icon or anything else you prefer. If you do not care about the topology, just arrange all the hosts in a grid.

If you have a lot of hosts, making each host a coloured rectangle might offer the highest density.

Comment: I just tried that but I found no way to create graphs thereof. I see your point with the overview so a big bunch of graphs, one for each host should be fine. At the moment I'd tend to use a screen and add all hosts + their uptimes their. However this is very tedious as I have to add every single host and cannot add all hosts of a group at once..

Comment: A screen is fine for a small number of hosts but will become unusable with a lot of hosts. If you have to configure a screen, map or any other entity with a large number of elements, in any case scripting that with the Zabbix API will be easier : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api .